# Finding the Jordan canonical form of A and Choose the correct option

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
  0&0&0&-4 \\ 1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&5 \\ 0&0&1&0
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then a Jordan canonical form of  A is

Choose the correct option

$a) \begin{pmatrix}
  -1&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&2&0 \\ 0&0&0&-2
 \end{pmatrix}$

$b) \begin{pmatrix}
  -1&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&2&0 \\ 0&0&0&-2
 \end{pmatrix}$

$c) \begin{pmatrix}
  1&1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&2&0 \\ 0&0&0&-2
 \end{pmatrix}$

$d) \begin{pmatrix}
  -1&1&0&0 \\ 0&-1&0&0 \\ 0&0&2&0 \\ 0&0&0&-2
 \end{pmatrix}$

My attempt : I know that  Determinant   of  A = product  of eigenvalues of A,  as  option c and d  is  not correct because  Here Determinant of A = 4

that is $ \det A =  -(-4) \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 &0\\0& 1 & 0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

I'm  in  confusion  about  option  a) and  b).......how  can I find the  Jordan canonical form of A ?

PLiz  help  me.

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Since all options are compatible with the check on det(A)=4, we need to determine the eigenvalues by $det(A-\lambda I)=0$ and the evaluate again the given options.

Note also that b is not a Jordan normal form.

Comment: okks   very  simple logics

Answer (score 4):

Another answer that requires only a very minimal amount of computations.

The trace of $A$ is preserved under similarity transformations. $\operatorname{Tr}(A) = 0+0+0+0 = \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4$ is enough to exclude **(c)** and **(d)**. As others have noted, **(b)** isn't even a Jordan canonical form (and by the way the matrix (b) is similar to (a) anyway).

So **(a)** is the only remaining option and must be correct.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix is diagonalizable, since it is a $4\times4$ matrix with $4$ distinct eigenvalues. Therefore, the correct option is a).

Comment: But  option a) and  option  b  has  same set of eigenvalue  i mean  both  have  same  eigenvalue

Comment: why option b)  is not correct ? as  per  ur  answer    option b has  also  distinct eigenvalue

Comment: @1TOPLOGY Yes, but the matrix from option b) is **not** a Jordan canonical form, since the upper left $2\times2$ submatrix is not a Jordan block.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is a result that a

1. triangular matrix is always diagonalizable with eigenvalues along the diagonal.
2. Combine this with the fact that permuting last column first makes $A$ triangular

---

**Edit** as mentioned in comments this answer is wrong. For 2. to work we will need not only permute rows or columns, but a **permutation similarity**, $P$ **and** $P^{-1}$ multiplying, one from each side. However part of 1. is true, the eigenvalues are always on the diagonal for a triangular matrix, so counting multiplicity can in that case give us hint of possible Jordan configurations.

Comment: No. The simplest Jordan matrix is $\left(\begin{matrix} 1& 1\\0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$ and it is not diagonalisable.

Comment: Yep of course you are right

Comment: Moreover, when you make a change of bases in an eigenvalue problem you have to make it in the form $A \to PAP^{-1}$, i.e., you have to make a row permutation that matches the column permutation, so you cannot use the transformation that you suggested. (Another reason why it doesn't work: if it did, then it would imply that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-4,1,1,1$, which is false).

Comment: Yep. Good addition. You almost never see in answers these days.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers to this question so far overlook the fact that the matrix in option (b) is not in Jordan canonical form in the first place, so you can eliminate that option without doing any work at all. After eliminating (c) and (d) as you’ve done, that leaves only (a).